# jquery ajax work in mozilla, but not IE

Tags: .net, ajax, jquery

I know jquery/ajax in IE is a common problem.  There is a lot of great advice here on stack overflow but none of it has worked for me yet.
The following code works just fine in firefox, but does not in IE:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false })
$.ajax({
 url: 'FunDataService.asmx/' + funDataMethod,
 type: 'POST', dataType: 'html', cache: false, timeout: 3000,
 error: function() {alert('Error updating fun information.  Refresh the page and try again.');},
 success: function(htmlFunInfo) {
  alert($(htmlFunInfo).text());
  $("#fundiv").html($(htmlFunInfo).text())},
 data: parameters
});
```

You can see my **anti-caching attempts**; I've also added random values to the URL.  I've also tried adding various **content headers** on the web service:

```
'        Context.Response.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8"
'        Context.Response.ContentType = "text/html"
Context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
```

The alert command is for debugging of course.  In FF, `$(htmlFunInfo).text()` is the div tags sent down from the server that I wish to insert.  In IE, it is empty string.

Does anyone know how to get access to this string value in IE?  Thanks!

**Edit**
The response from the server is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="tempuri.org/">
  <div>stuff</div>
  <div>more stuff</div>
</string>
```

Increasingly I think that is what's wrong, that I need to avoid the wrapping around the divs.

**Edit 2**  That's it!  In my server code, I replaced:

```
Return RemarkHtml
```

with

```
Context.Response.Write(RemarkHtml)
```

This avoided the tags surrounding the divs, and now I'm good.  Still, I think it's a big problem that in IE, you just can't get to the contents of tags using .text().

Thanks guys!

Comment: You shouldn't need anti-caching techniques for a POST, only for GET requests.  Also, jQuery handles it for you even if you were using a GET.

Comment: ah, okay.  I've been trying everything though.  I'm about to wave the dead chicken.  I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
alert($(htmlFunInfo).text());
$("#fundiv").html($(htmlFunInfo).text());
```

Try

```
alert(htmlFunInfo);
$("#fundiv").html(htmlFunInfo);
```

The issue is that calls to `.text()` and `.html()` get the text and HTML *contents* of the selected node(s).  It looks like what you want to do here is actually inject the entire response into `#fundiv`.

Comment: I tried that. I should have mentioned it. When I do that, the alert shows my intended html (1) surrounded with a <string xmlns="tempuri.org/">&lt; and a corresponding end tag, and (2) prepended with: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> . Inserted into my page is this text; instead of intended formatted data, the browser shows the actual markup!  Not good.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried changing the jQuery Ajax dataType option to 'text'?

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false })
$.ajax({
 url: 'FunDataService.asmx/' + funDataMethod,
 type: 'POST', 

 dataType: 'text', // instead of 'html'

 cache: false, 
 timeout: 3000,
 error: function() {
     alert('Error updating fun information.  Refresh the page and try again.');
 },
 success: function(htmlFunInfo) {
    alert($(htmlFunInfo).text());
    $("#fundiv").html($(htmlFunInfo).text())
 },
 data: parameters
});
```

**EDIT:**

An alternative would be the jQuery .load() method. It appends the result of an AJAX response to a jQuery selected object. You can probably use ajaxSetup() to configure ajaxOptions for the request.

.load() doc:

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load#urldatacallback

```
$.ajaxSetup({
 type: 'POST', 
 dataType: 'text', 
 cache: false, 
 timeout: 3000,
 error: function() {
     alert('Error updating fun information.  Refresh the page and try again.');
 },
 data: parameters
});

$("#fundiv").load( 'FunDataService.asmx/' + funDataMethod );
```

Comment: I did actually, after my original post.  (I'm still working on this issue.)  Sadly, it did not make a difference.  Using .text() still does not get me anything in IE, like it does in FF.

Comment: ah, so you're trying to get the contents of the response into the <div/>. i don't think you need .text() at all. have you tried .html(htmlFunInfo)?

Answer (score 1):

I dont fully understand why that works in FF and not in IE but I'm guessing it has something to do with differences in how each browsers create the node heiarchy.

In either case, content inside the variable htmlFunInfo is a string so there is no need to call text(). Like Jason says, it should work if you take out the .text().

Comment: That certainly makes sense.  You think the problem then is the <string> tag that surrounds my text, or the <?xml> tag at the beginning?  In FF, doing htmlFunInfo.text() gets me just my intended html, without the extra stuff.  So, for IE, I guess I need to keep that from coming down in the first place?  That's actually why I was trying those content headers on the server, to try to take out that extra stuff.  Any ideas how I could do that?